# how can i assign no in column A based on Value in B and if there is any Duplicated values assign the same no.?

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

if Column "A" was empty how can i make excel assign unique no# to unique cells and duplicated no# to duplicated cells just like the image attached.

Comment: You can probably do this with a formula. What's the logic for deciding what the next serial number in column B is for a new number? I don't understand the 'if column "A" was empty' comment. What do you mean by that?

Comment: yes you can do this with a function but the whole sheet will be wiped out and replaced with new sheet with every update so i had to do it with VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am sure there is probably an easier way to accomplish your task, this one seems to work okay (disclaimer: lightly tested).

So essentially, `serialNumber` attempts to find the highest value in `Col A`. If none is found, it's assigned a value of `1`.

`RetCel` attempts to set itself to a previous cell that matches. If no match is found, it will assign the current `serialNumber` value. If a match is found, then it will use the value of the match.

`serialNumber` only increases itself when the value has been used.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AssignUnique()

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim ws As Worksheet, RngA As Range, RngB As Range, cel As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Set RngA = ws.UsedRange.Columns("A")
    Set RngB = ws.UsedRange.Columns("B")

    If RngA.Column = 2 Then
        'In the event RngA is empty, UsedRange will make it col B
        Set RngA = RngA.Offset(, -1)
        Set RngB = RngB.Offset(, -1)
        If RngA.Column <> 1 Then
            Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1000, , "Error setting RngA"
        End If
    End If

    Dim RetCel As Range, serialNumber As Long
    serialNumber = WorksheetFunction.Max(RngA)
    If serialNumber = 0 Then serialNumber = 1
    For Each cel In RngB.Cells
        Set RetCel = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set RetCel = ws.Cells.Find(cel.Value, After:=Cells(cel.Row - 1, 2), _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        Debug.Print RetCel.Address
        On Error GoTo ErrHandler
        If cel.Value = vbNullString Then
            'Do Nothing
        ElseIf RetCel Is Nothing Then
            cel.Offset(, -1).Value = serialNumber
            serialNumber = serialNumber + 1
        Else
            cel.Offset(, -1).Value = RetCel.Offset(, -1).Value
            If cel.Offset(, -1).Value = vbNullString Then
                cel.Offset(, -1).Value = serialNumber
                serialNumber = serialNumber + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next cel
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Runtime # " & Err.Number

End Sub
```

Comment: that worked fine i tested it on longer sheets and its fast and perfect, before i have used the worksheetfunction.lookup but it return wrong no. when the sheet is long. thank you